# Unable To RDC One PC

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access

I can Remote Desktop any PC under our domain, except this ONE!  When I try to RDC this one PC, I get an error of:

> Connection was denied because the user account is not authorized for
>   remote logon

I have Domain Admin Credentials, so what would be keeping me from being able to RDC this 1 PC?

Comment: Ensure that the computer denying RDC is actually logged in to the domain and has RDC enabled.

Comment: @Ouroborus - it is logged into the domain and I can RDC from that PC to another one, just not vice versa

Comment: Incoming and outgoing RDC are different things (server vs client). It's entirely possible to RDC out but have incoming RDC disabled. See if you can RDC into that machine using an account that can log into that machine directly.

Comment: My credentials are able to log directly into that machine (same credentials I attempt to RDC into with).  I will check the settings, in the a.m. when I can get back in front of the PC.

Comment: Maybe [this thread](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/458408-the-connection-was-denied-because-the-user-account-is-not-authorized-for) will help you in the morning. Outside of that, I'm not sure what else might be wrong.

Comment: @user2676140 Ensure the PC is joined to the correct domain for the administrator account you're RDP'ing into it as. Perhaps unjoin it from the domain, reboot, rejoin it to the domain, reboot, and then try again. Ensure there is no local (or domain) group policies that are explicitly denying this access for this account. Add the account to the PCs local security group Remote Desktop Users and try again. Add a different NON domain admin test account to the local Remote Desktop Users and try RDP'ing into it and compare.  Quick things I would try and then look over event viewer logs as well.

Comment: @LMFAO_A_JOKE - unjoin from domain, reboot, join to domain and RDP incoming works now.  1st time I have ever had this occur!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Unable To RDC One PC**
>
> I can Remote Desktop any PC under our domain, except this ONE! When I
>   try to RDC this one PC, I get an error of:
>
> **`Connection was denied because the user account is not authorized for remote logon`**
>
> I have Domain Admin Credentials, so what would be keeping me from
>   being able to RDC this 1 PC?

A few items to consider for a solution to this problem. . .

1. Ensure the PC is joined to the correct domain for the administrator
   account you're RDP'ing into it as.
2. Unjoin the PC from the domain, reboot it, rejoin it to the domain,
   reboot it again, and then try to RDP into it again.
3. Ensure there is no *local* (or *domain*) **group policies** that are
   *explicitly* denying access for this account to RDP into this machine.
4. Add the account to the Windows local security group named **Remote
   Desktop Users**and try again.
5. Add a different non-domain admin test account to the local **Remote
   Desktop Users** security group, and try RDP'ing into it and compare
   results.

These are quick things I would try and then...

6. Look over Windows **Event Viewer** logs.

Comment: I had this issue with a Windows 7 PC. Nothing from the above points helped. Finally I could find the reason: In Windows 7 the user which wants to run RDC on this PC must be added explicitly under Remotedesktop [Right click on This PC -> Remote settings -> Remotedesktop ]